# Aws lambda image upload issue

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, fetch, multipartform-data, jira-rest-api

I am trying to upload a PNG image (attachment) as well as some text to my aws lambda (which is integrated with an api gateway)from Vue JS using fetch, the purpose of this is to forward this form data to JIRA cloud rest api to create an "issue ticket" in JIRA with an accompanying attachment.

I do this by placing the image and the text into form data then POST the formdata to my lambda, as multipart/form-data using fetch.

Client POST Request:

```
   var formData = new FormData();
     formData.set('title', 'some text');
     formData.set('comment', 'some text');
     formData.append('file', file, file.name);

    let options = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
    };

    return fetch(url, options)
    .then(response => {
      console.log('Response: ', response);
      return response.text();
    })
    .then((result) => {
      console.log('Result: ', result);
    })
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

I have configured my API-Gateway to convert multipart/form-data to a base 64 string once the formdata has been received by the lambda, I use the [lambda-multipart-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lambda-multipart-parser) to retrieve the data from the base 64 string. Next the lambda then goes and creates the JIRA ticket and then attaches the image to that ticket. The JIRA ticket is successfully created however the the problem I am having is with the image, it seems the image is attached to the ticket but is corrupted/has errors and is unable to be opened.

Partial Lambda Code:

```
let data = await parser.parse(event);
let formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append('file', data.files[0].content, data.files[0].filename);

let boundary = formdata.getBoundary();

let attachment = {
  method: 'POST',
   headers: {
     'Accept': 'application/json',
     'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data;boundary=${boundary}`,
     'X-Atlassian-Token': 'no-check'
   },
   body: formdata
  };

return fetch(`https://hostname/rest/api/3/issue/${issueId}/attachments`, attachment)
.then(response => {
return response.text();
})
.then((result) => {
console.log('Result: ', result);
})
.catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Any suggestions as to why the image file has errors is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Correct content-type?

Comment: @jarmod when i check the request headers in browser they're set to multipart/form-data with an accompanying boundary.

Comment: I read that `fetch` can generate the Content-Type header with boundary so you don't need to supply it. I'd guess that what you've done would match but might be worth checking.

Comment: @jarmod just tried without setting the Content-Type in the lambda, the attachment still goes through but still has issues :(